# How to bind JQuery event to a selector with variable id or class?

Tags: jquery

I have a page that can have a variable number of tables.  Each table has an id with a number associated with it (for example, table1, table2, table3).
A column in each table contains a link that I want to bind a click event to.  I have a variable that holds the id for the link selector (for example, invlink1, invlink2, invlink3).  How do I bind this variable selector id to the event?

I currently have:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(){
                            console.log('table' + $(this).attr('id'));
                            var tid = $(this).attr('id');
                            console.log(tid);
                            var tabnum = tid.slice(7,8);
                            var invoicelink = "$(\'#invlink" +tabnum+ "\')";
                            console.log(invoicelink);
                            $('[id^="rnote"]').bind('click',addreasonnote);
                            invoicelink.bind('click',viewinvoicedetails);
                            $('[id^="reason"]').bind('change',selectreasoncode);
                        },
```

so, invoicelink holds the id of the selector.
I also suspect I should be using a class instead of an id for the selector, but that's not causing the syntax error.

Comment: What issue you are running into? You should be using class instead of id. Provide http://jsfiddle.net/ to get quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate an ID string in the selector:

```
$("#" + invoicelink)...
```